# Build lambda expression dynamically

Tags: linq, sorting, dynamic, lambda, linq-to-objects

I am trying to sort a object collection dynamically. Ideally I would want it to do the below functionality where I could specify the criteria at runtime.

```
_group.OrderByDescending(rec => "rec.CalculatedRecord.GL.PropertyValue").Take(Convert.ToInt16(_filters.Value))
```

I tried dynamic linq which didn't work.

```
var query = (from enumerable in _group
                           orderby "rec.CalculatedRecord.GL.PropertyValue").  descending 
                          select enumerable).Take(5);
```

Comment: Not sure if it's still alive but there used to be a dynamic linq library that helped you do this. Have a look here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: Do you have an example that works on Object Collections

Comment: Similiar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299095/selecting-columns-in-linq-using-system-linq-expressions-api/11299683#11299683

Answer (score 0):

A note on why the second one shouldn't work: your object of enumeration is called `enumerable` yet in your string you are still using `rec` as in the lambda earlier.  changing the string to use `enumerable` instead of `rec` might alleviate your issues.

Comment: Corrected, Do you have an example that works on Object Collections

Answer (score 0):

The `OrderByDescending` method takes a parameter of `Func<TSource, TKey>`.  While you can insert a lambda here, as is the most common use case, you can also pass in a variable.  The variable can be dynamically assigned based on whatever you logic might be.

I have had to infer your class structure, but here's a basic example:

```
    public class Record
    {
        public CalculatedRecord CalculatedRecord { get; set; }
    }

    public class CalculatedRecord
    {
        public GL GL { get; set; }
    }

    public class GL
    {
        public PropertyValue PropertyValue1 { get; set; }
        public PropertyValue PropertyValue2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class PropertyValue { }
```

Then you can create the following logic:

```
    public class TestHarness
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            IEnumerable<Record> Group = new List<Record>();

            //Simple flag
            bool someCriteria = true;

            //Define orderByFunc
            Func<Record, PropertyValue> orderByFunc;

            //Assign the order by function based on someCriteria 
            if (someCriteria)
            {
                orderByFunc = record => 
                              record.CalculatedRecord.GL.PropertyValue1;
            }
            else
            {
                orderByFunc = record => 
                              record.CalculatedRecord.GL.PropertyValue2;
            }

            //Execute OrderBy
            var updated = Group.OrderByDescending(orderByFunc).Take(5);

        }
    }
```

However, this doesn't allow you to generate the Func dynamically at runtime.  In order to do that you will need to build an `Expression` using expression trees and then compile it.  You can follow the steps at  [Expression.Lambda and query generation at runtime, simplest "Where" example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315819/expression-lambda-and-query-generation-at-runtime-simplest-where-example)

Comment: This might also be helpful: http://flee.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home