# Expression.Lambda and query generation at runtime, nested property “Where” example

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, dynamic-language-runtime

I found very nice answer on a question about building Expression Tree for Where query.

[Expression.Lambda and query generation at runtime, simplest "Where" example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315819/expression-lambda-and-query-generation-at-runtime-simplest-where-example)

Can someone help me and show me how this example could be implemented in the scenario with nested property. I mean instead of:

```
var result = query.Where(item => item.Name == "Soap")
```

With that solution:

```
var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "item");

var prop = Expression.Property(item, "Name");

var soap = Expression.Constant("Soap");

var equal = Expression.Equal(prop, soap);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(equal, item);

var result = queryableData.Where(lambda);
```

How can I build the tree for the following?

```
var result = query.Where(item => item.Data.Name == "Soap").
```

Comment: What is `Data`? Specify this property

Comment: Sergii thanks for help. I finally resolve that - you can check it below update. Second line is added and third is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer was originally posted by the OP in the question.)

The problem can be solved with:

```
var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "item");

var dataExpr = Expression.Property(item, "Data");

var prop = Expression.Property(dataExpr, "Name");

var soap = Expression.Constant("Soap");

var equal = Expression.Equal(prop, soap);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(equal, item);

var result = queryableData.Where(lambda);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the same answer as posted above, but I find this more readable in terms of visualizing an expression tree:

```
var parameterItem = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "item");

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(
            Expression.Property(
                parameterItem, 
                "Data"
            ), 
            "Name"
        ), 
        Expression.Constant("Soap")
    ), 
    parameterItem
);

var result = queryableData.Where(lambda);
```