# Search tags within content ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a tag table with an id and just the title of the tags. I have a content table with an id and a string MainContent.

I would like to search the MainContent with all the tags from the tag table and get the result with just the content which contains any of the tags within the content table.

How would I go about this using ASP.NET Core (I have the latest 2.2) with Entity Framework Core 2?

```
public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagTitle { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public string MainContent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Anything that we can go with? Schema ?

Comment: I have added the classes I am using

Comment: I would write a custom where.. check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315819/expression-lambda-and-query-generation-at-runtime-simplest-where-example/8315901#8315901

Comment: There is no relationship between `Tag` and `Content`, what do you mean by ` search the MainContent with all the tags from the tag table`. Is there any demo data and share us the logic to get your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Are you trying to migrate to the database?

If so, then you have to determine the relationship between Content and Tag.

In this case I'm assuming Many Contents have Zero-to-Many Tags. So you need a Many-to-Many relationship.

Create another Model named: ContentTags

```
public class ContentTags
{
public Content Content {get; set;}
public int ContentId {get; set;}

public Tag Tag {get; set;}
public int TagId {get; set;}
}
```

I'm assuming you already know about the ApplicatonDbContext.

Comment: The tables are not joined at all, all im trying to do is search the content table by looping through all the tags from the tag table

Comment: Well you have to join them. Otherwise I don't get how will you be able to get the contents.

Do you want to go with string search? I don't quite get it.