# Selecting Columns in LINQ using System.Linq.Expressions API

Tags: .net, linq, linq-expressions

I'm trying to use LINQ expressions to dynamically select columns from an `IEnumerable` into a result set that I can bind to my UI.  At this point I am having a hard time just grasping the basics of projection in LINQ expressions.

Let's say I have a list of strings like so:

```
Dim myStrings = {"one", "two", "three"}.ToList()
```

Using lambda expressions I can easily select out a collection of string lengths by doing:

```
Dim myStringLengths = myStrings.Select(Function(x) x.Length)
```

The result of this statement would leave me with a collection called `myStringLengths` that have the elements `3, 3, 5`.

What I can't seem to figure out is how I can produce the equivalent result using a LINQ expression.

**Edit:** When I say LINQ expression, I am talking about using the API in the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace, not the standard form of a LINQ statment or lambda expression.  As you can clearly see above, I am already familiar with how to generate a projection that way.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) allows you to select columns at runtime.

Comment: I'd prefer to not build out my expressions using strings.

Comment: What is the expression you wish to build?

Comment: @Hogan: `select { list of fields chosen at runtime }`

Comment: I can't imagine how to do this without the fields being listed as strings at runtime -- am I missing something?

Comment: Under the hood, lambda expressions aren't much more than simplified versions of LINQ expression trees (at least that's how I understand it so far).  It's possible to dynamically build a lambda expression with types that aren't known until runtime using LINQ expressions, which is what I'm trying to do.  The property I want to select is available to me through a PropertyInfo object, which does expose the name as a string, but I want something that will be a little more strongly typed than simply creating a CSV and passing it to a custom SQL string parsing library.

Comment: Some possible clues here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/04/25/using-linq-expressions-to-generate-dynamic-methods.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "x");
 var length = Expression.PropertyOrField(item, "Length");

 new string[] {"one", "two", "three"}
      .AsQueryable()
      .Select(Expression.Lambda<Func<string, int>>(length, item));
```

You need an IQueryable to use expressions (you can bring it back to IEnumerable with ToList or similiar).
Then you generate the Lambda as an expression tree (the length example is done above).
Sorry its in C#

Comment: If you don't know the types at compile time, the expression will get a little more complicated as you will need to include cast expressions to cast the input parameter into the correct type (derived at runtime) before accessing the field. The easiest way I find is to write the lambda you want to use, then deconstruct it into expression operations.

Comment: Nice.  I was looking at `Expression.Lambda`... but why?  Can't you just go right to `Expression.PropertyOrField`?

Comment: Because Select takes a func as its argument (its a projection from one object to another). Like any other method call you must obey the signature. System.Linq.Queryable.Select<TSource, TResult>(this System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,TResult>>)

Comment: Thanks, this is much more like what I'm looking for.  One hurdle I will have to jump is the fact that currently I have a non-generic IEnumerable to work with.  This prevents me from even using .Select() (at least I have not found a way yet).  I have a PropertyInfo object for the field I want to select, so I have the name and type of the property, as well as the type of the underlying class, available to me.  I'll mess around with deconstructing the lambda for a bit.

Comment: There is an overload of AsQueryable for non-generic IEnumerable, it just takes a few more Expressions to cast the items.

Comment: I don't see an overload for AsQueryable, the only version of IEnumerable.AsQueryable() that I see returns me a non-generic IQueryable (which also doesn't have Select).  I'm not sure how to use the generic Cast method using a type I don't know until runtime.  (E.g - myCollection.AsQueryable().Cast<someDynamicType>()) to get the queryable I need.  Not sure if you were referring to a way to do that using LINQ expressions as well.

Comment: It'll be easier if you ask another question for this, detail the actual problem you want solved.

Comment: I lead you astray, use myEnumerable.Cast<object>().AsQueryable() then your expressions will need to deal with casting.

Comment: I've detailed what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish in a follow up question if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312570/using-expression-call-with-queryable-select-with-a-type-known-only-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

In C# it would look like this

```
var myStringLengths = myStrings
                        .Select((s) => s.Length);
```

Comment: That is simply the C# version of the VB statement I used above.

Comment: @MikeC Yes, can you please give a better example of what you are looking for in your question.  Starting and ending values would help.

Comment: I added the explicit expected result of my query above, it's no more than a collection of integers representing the length of the strings.  The start values and desired operation are already in the question.